# Heroku: Is my discord bot making web requests?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord

So i found this on Heroku's help page: [dyno sleeping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC67P.png) and I am concerned about my bot being online 24/7 so I tested to see if that was true, and the good thing is that it wasn't! But thing is, is my bot making web requests? Because if you pay attention to the highlighted text, you can notice that it says that: "**Apps that only utilise a free worker dyno do not sleep, because they do not respond to web requests. Be mindful of this as they may run 24/7 and consume from your pool of hours.**" I still changed the **web dyno** to **worker dyno** But i can't tell if it is working 24/7 even if I shutdown my PC So if someone know that answer for this question, please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: I do not know why you guys downvoted my question, I had that doubt since I started my Bot. But it doesn't matter too much now since it is already solved idiots.

Answer (score 1):

When running a worker the process (in this case Discord Bot) runs in the background and it does not go to sleep (unlike free Web Dynos after 30 min inactivity.)

You can see the logs in your Heroku Dashboard (`https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{app_name}/logs`, you should see some activity and definitely the process not terminating.